# prototype.js wrap each h3 tag with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

excuse any ignorance but I'm a regular jQuery user and have to add some code on a prototype.js website. I've checked through the docs but am still none the wiser as to how I can simply wrap each h3 element in a sidebar with a span tag.

I have tried two options, neither of which work…

```
$$('.ipsLayout_right h3').wrap(span);
```

and

```
$$(".ipsLayout_right h3").each(function(element) {
    element.replace("<h3><span>" + element.innerHTML + "</span></h3>");
});
```

Can anyone help get this sorted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrototypeJS doesn't have jQuery's set-based approach. The closest it comes is its [`invoke` function](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/), which lets you "invoke" a method on all elements in an `Enumeration`:

```
$$('.ipsLayout_right h3').invoke("wrap", "span");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/jojeq/1) - but see note below

---

Side note: It's invalid to wrap an `h3` in a `span`. The content model of [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is *phrasing content* (like the text in a paragraph), but [`h3`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) can only be used where *flow content* (like entire paragraphs) is expected.

If you want to wrap the *contents* of the `h3`, allowing for the possibility that those contents may well be text nodes and not elements, then I'm pretty sure you have to do a lot more work:

```
$$('.ipsLayout_right h3').each(function(h3) {
  var span = new Element('span');
  while (h3.firstChild) {
    span.appendChild(h3.firstChild);
  }
  h3.appendChild(span);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/jojeq/2/)

Comment: Of course! Have moved this and can conform it's now working thank you. 

Is there also an innerWrap function or similar available that would enable me to change <h3><a href="#">text here</a></h3> to <h3><span><a href="#">text here</a><span></h3> - I don't want to include the link as a selector as not all h3 tags have links in them

Comment: @JamesPayne: I was just looking at the API to see if there was (been that long). I don't think there is. I've shown how to do it above, but it feels so *manual*. :-)

Comment: Ha ha thank for your help it's very much appreciated. Safe to say I won't ever be using it in any of my own projects!

Comment: @Aleski: Since your question and my answer to it are OT for this user's question, let's remove our comments (I've already removed mine; I assume you've seen it by now).